# How to prevent gaming a voting system where people can vote once per day?

Tags: php, algorithm, lamp, ranking, voting-system

I've implemented a voting system for videos online, wherein visitors can only cast a vote once in any given day. I use combination of their email address and timestamp to ensure that each vote is unique for that day.

As you might guess, this lead to people gaming the system by registering throwaway email addresses at mailinator.com and the like, so I'm wondering if anyone's tried implementing any other voting algorithms that allow for multiple votes by the same person. In addition, this setup means that if a video #1 has more people associated with it than video #2, video #1 is already at an unfair advantage.

I'm thinking about a ranked system, but I'm not totally sure how that could prevent anyone from gaming the system with fake email addresses. The problem I'm trying to solve is like this:

> Given 3 videos, A, B and X. A has 5 people in it, B has 2, and X has 4.
>   Assuming that X is the best video of the three, and that people can vote every day, is there a voting system that will help "B" rise to the top?

Like I said, I my proposed ranked system, would posit that if the amount of #2's outnumber the #1's, it's safe to assume **that** should be the winner, but that seems incomplete.

Has anyone tackled anything like this before? Keep in mind, these are pretty low volume results (we average about 500 votes/7 days), so 2 people can really make a difference.

This is on a LAMP (PHP) stack in a shared hosting environment, if it helps.

Also, if you're wondering why we're allowing multiple votes by the same person, it's because the higher ups realize this helps drive traffic to the site, and they really enjoy seeing graphs go up (despite the fact the subsequent hits are pretty meaningless).

Thanks in advance, and if you need any other information please let me know.

Comment: Sounds like a good use for the [EverCookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie).

Comment: @jnpcl: those things should be banned. Use a real login system instead (or use OpenID), period.

Comment: @Alexandre: Apologies, sarcasm is lost in text. I should have added a smiley.  ;)

Comment: @jnpcl: no problem. Some people would unfortunately not have been sarcastic about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually asking about two separate things:

First, how can you prevent people gaming the system? This is pretty intractable. You can raise the bar for placing a vote, by requiring registration, a minimum reputation like SO, or other restrictions, but ultimately all you can hope to do is reduce cheating, not eliminate it. Consider that people successfully register multiple times for physical political elections, then evaluate how likely it is that you can eliminate all cheating on your site.

Second, how do you give a fair quality ranking to different items that may have different popularity and have been around for different times? One very good solution is described [here](http://blog.reddit.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html) by Randall Munroe. That article links to the actual algorithm, which is fairly straightforward to implement.

Comment: That solution you linked to on XKCD looks like it could have some legs. I'm going to look into that further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to your problem without a login system. People will keep defeating your system unless you provide them with a real authentication system which takes several steps to create an account. OpenID is great for this by the way.

Do not use heavy cookie based stuff (especially do not use Evercookie). This is an offense to your users' privacy. I would never want a zombie cookie on my computer.

If they keep gaming you, there is nothing you can do, except manually flagging garbage accounts and deleting the corresponding votes.

Or you can do a reputation based system, with a minimal rep needed to vote (like StackOverflow).

Look at [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) if you want a fast secure working solution.

Comment: openid is not going to solve the problem of identifying people online, not merely accounts. it will only shift the problem from the ever so slightly determined to the slightly more determined.

Comment: @hop: Openid has the advantage of 1) being easy to implement 2) discourage people from creating a lot of accounts since it is lengthy to open many accounts. This alone will discourage some users. The rep thing is good too.

Comment: "some users" is exactly what makes this solution useless, and what is a "lengthy" process now (which i doubt very much) will be automated tomorrow. as i said: it will only shift the problem to those cheaters that are slightly more determined then the rest.

Comment: OpenID is definitely another option that I hadn't even considered. I'm going to assume that most of the world has either a Gmail/Yahoo/Windows Live account, and iirc, they're all OpenId providers, so that could be reasonably easy for those in charge to buy into. Thanks!

Comment: @leo: also you could ban disposable emails in the first place, you have a list here: http://www.sizlopedia.com/2007/05/27/top-20-temporary-and-disposable-email-services/

Answer (score 1):

There is this Q&A platform on the net -- don't know if you ever heard of that -- it's called stackoverflow.com ;-)

Maybe you can adopt the rating system at this site? I find it quite clever to allow only users with a given rating to manipulate the system in several ways. You can select users by age of their account (e.g. votes count only from 2 weeks after registration) or by some kind of reputation system.

Comment: What I find clever is to disallow users with zero rep (ie. dummy accounts) to manipulate the system in any way.